# How can I create a 1:1 relationship in Entity Framework?

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first, entity-framework-ctp5

I want to store some objects where there is exactly one Bar for each Foo.

I have some POCO objects that look something like this:

```
public class Foo
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string FooProperty { get; set; }
    public int BarId { get; set; }
    public virtual Bar Bar { get; set; }
}
public class Bar
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string BarProperty { get; set; }
    public int FooId { get; set; }
    public virtual Foo Foo { get; set; }
}
```

The Foo and Bar have a 1:1 relationship, and based on the reading I've done I tried the following in my DbContext class:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<OneToManyCascadeDeleteConvention>();
    modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<ManyToManyCascadeDeleteConvention>();

    modelBuilder.Entity<Foo>()
                   .HasRequired(x => x.Bar)
                   .WithRequiredPrincipal(x => x.Foo);

    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
}
```

The backing store is SQL Server, and this does indeed create me tables with a 1:1 relationship. **However**, the FK relationship from `Bar` to `Foo` is on the `Id` field of both tables, whereas I would expect it to be from the `FooId` field of the `Bar` table to the `Id` field of the `Foo` table.

It seems that EF has decided to keep the PK (Id) field of both tables in sync, and is essentially ignoring my `BarId`/`FooId` columns.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you sure you want a 1:1 relationship? If for every foo there is a single bar, and every bar there is a single foo, EF will use the primary keys for the relationship, and it probably should.  Are you sure you don't want a 1:many or 1:0..1 relationship?

If you want a Foo to be able to have many bars, so you can define a FK you could change your fluent:

```
  modelBuilder.Entity<Foo>()
                .HasRequired(x => x.Bar)
                .WithMany()
                .HasForeignKey(f => f.BarId);
```

Here's a blog post about [One-To-One foreign key relationships](http://weblogs.asp.net/manavi/archive/2011/05/01/associations-in-ef-4-1-code-first-part-5-one-to-one-foreign-key-associations.aspx) which might help

Comment: thanks. I do want 1:1, and I suppose a shared PK is OK. The reason I added the FooId/Foo and BarId/Bar properties to my POCO objects was because that's the recommended thing to do according to the "how to" articles I've read. It works in the 1:many case, and it seems a bit odd not to have these parameters just because it's 1:1. I thought the code-first stuff was meant to largely remove the coupling between the backing store and the object...